# Injective function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Anyone, who can help me to decide whether $v(x,y)=x\sqrt{x+y}+xy+7$ is a injective function. It is easy for me to decide whether a function of one variable is injective, but I am having trouble with more variable cases like this one.

Hope someone can help

Comment: $v(0,y)=7\;\;\forall y$

Comment: Consider the level sets of this function (the sets $C_r=\{(x,y)\mid v(x,y)=r\}$). $v$ is constant on each such (nonempty) set. If you can find a level set containing more than one point, you will have shown the function is not injective.

Comment: An injective function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ is not impossible, but its expression will not be so simple...

Comment: @ajotatxe
An injective function from $\mathbb R^2 $ to $ \mathbb R $ with $x$ or $y$ continuous is impossible. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695302/does-there-exist-an-injective-function-f-mathbb-r2-to-mathbb-r-such-that?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move in a direction in the $(x,y)$-plane that is perpendicular to the gradient, you're following a level curve of this function.  If there are non-empty level curves, then clearly the function is not one-to-one.